# Perl: compare current time to a specific time to

Tags: perl

I am very new to perl. I am working on a script that runs everyday. I want to check that current time is less than a specific time. My current solution is that I extract `hour` and `min` from `localtime` and then compare it. But I was told to find a better solution.

Current code:

```perl
my $flag;
for (;;) {
    $flag = GetValue();
    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
    if( $flag ) {
        #do action here
        last;
    } elsif ( $hour <= 17 ) {
        if( $min <=30 ) {
            print STDOUT "Keep running till 17:30 \n";
            sleep 300;
        } else {
            die "Error";
        }
    } else {
        die "Error";
    }
}
```

Basically, the statement `$flag = GetValue();` sometimes returns undefined value unexpectedly and causes the script to fail. So we want to check if $flag defined. If it is defined then we execute some code and exit the for loop. Else we check the time. If the time is less that 17:30 then we want to wait for some time and try to get the value of flag again. I only **need to change the logic of comparing current time to 17:30**

I want my something like:

```perl
} elsif ( $current_time <= 17:30 ) {
   print STDOUT "Keep running till 17:30 \n";
   sleep 300;
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: "I was told to find a better solution" --> What is the issue with your current code? How do you define "better"?

Comment: It works. They just want a solution which is easier to read than having nested if else blocks.

Comment: The most solid way to deal with date-times is to use a good library, like `DateTime`.  But, if you really only ever want to compare the current (local) time to a given hour-minute that's probably an overkill.  What is wrong with `elsif ($hour < 17 or ($hour == 17 and $min <= 30))` ?

Comment: @zdim Not sure why it was a problem. I thought the code was readable enough. Or maybe I took a small suggestion too seriously. Anyways, I'm only doing this one time related operation in whole  the code so I'll go with `elsif ($hour < 17 or ($hour == 17 and $min <= 30))` instead of using DateTime.

Comment: I think the code you posted is fine although I would rearrange it. Adding extra third-party and non-core dependencies adds its own problems and complexities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good and solid way to deal with date-times is to use a good library, like [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

```
my $dt_mark = DateTime
    -> now(time_zone => 'local')
    -> set(hour => 17, minute => 30);

for (;;) { 
   ...

   elsif ( DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local') <= $dt_mark ) {
      ...
```

One can avoid constructing a new object for every comparison but that would make the code more complicated. Note that `DateTime` is a large library and this could be an overkill.

If the purpose is indeed to merely compare the current time to a fixed hour-minute then perhaps

```
elsif ( $hour < 17 or ($hour == 17 and $min <= 30) )
```

is good enough?

Or form and use strings that can be lexically compared

```
elsif ( sprintf("%02d%02d", $hour, $min) lt '1730' )
```

---

For the stated purpose it is fine to do

```
my (undef, $min, $hour) = localtime(time);
```

This may be clearer as well as it directly indicates which parts of `localtime`'s return are used.

Can also leave out `time`, per [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime)

> **localtime EXPR**
> **localtime**
> ...
> If EXPR is omitted, `localtime` uses the current time (as returned by `time`).

Comment: Or, put the logic in a sub so that your main code is just `elsif ( current_time_is_less_than_17_30() )`.

Comment: Note that DateTime is a fairly heavy lift, and most of the things that make it attractive (leap seconds, proper time zones, etc) aren't a factor here.

Comment: @briandfoy  Well, I say that in the answer, as the reason to offer alternatives ... ? (Did you read that?)  Still, it is a good thing to bring up in general, specially to people unaccustomed to Perl

Comment: You say it eventually, but your first paragraph sets the frame for everything that comes after it. Don't recommend going to a heavyweight module right off the bat.

Comment: @briandfoy Besides, those aren't "_most of the things_" that make it attractive -- it's more its completeness and uniform API, and absence of trickery (unlike my otherwise favorite `Time::Piece`) -- and not to forget the ecosystem

Comment: @briandfoy "_Don't recommend going to a heavyweight module right off the bat_"  -- for basic questions and when people are completely new to Perl I think it is actually a good manner to first bring up rounded and solid libraries.  If someone isn't going to read past the first line I can't help that

Comment: I don't use DateTime unless it's the only way to solve the problem. Your tastes and preferences can vary. I think your answer would be much better if you never mentioned DateTime. You absolutely can help people who won't keep reading since you control what you write and how you set the tone.

Comment: @briandfoy  "_I don't use DateTime unless..._"    Incidentally, I am bothered by how heavy it is, and personally I tend to use `Time::Piece` (wrapped in my own stuff).  However, I can't honestly flatly recommend it to people inexperienced with Perl, after all the quirks I've ran into over time.  (And I definitely can't recommend a manual patchwork of different tools)  Unsatisfactory situation in Perl in my view, which is a little silly given how often datetimes are needed.

Comment: @briandfoy "_You absolutely can help people who won't keep reading since you control what you write and how you set the tone_"  -- I refuse that pressure for instant deliverables.  Please scan the two paragraphs with clear code snippets (it's not two screenfulls).  More to the point, while one can indeed often separate the main point or recommendation, what when that is not possible?  I like the default of considering the whole post.